# How to create file browser horizontal tree like windows using visual studio 2008

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, file-browser

I want to create something like the windows file browser upper bar.. Like url browser, see the image below. Using visual studio 2008.

[image: click here to see..]

Is there any control that can do this? Free or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in controls that do this.

Infragistics sells [their own version](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winnavigationbar.aspx).